# server version incompatibility installing apc

Tags: php, mysql, apache2, ubuntu-12.04, apc

My server has fell over when trying to install apc. The /var/log/syslog sais:

```
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23765]: Upgrading MySQL tables if necessary.
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23768]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23768]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23768]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23768]: Error: Server version (5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) does not match with the version of
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23768]: the server (5.5.32) with which this program was built/distributed. You can
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23768]: use --skip-version-check to skip this check.
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23768]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23793]: Checking for insecure root accounts.
Aug 20 01:16:00 vps29386 /etc/mysql/debian-start[23798]: Triggering myisam-recover for all MyISAM tables
```

Could you please help me?
This has been posted at [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com), but nobody is looking the post...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstalling the VPS was for me the only way to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

APC was not built on your machine and it seems you are using an incompatible repository for the binaries. You can do build APC by yourself (download source from http://pecl.php.net/package/APC and compile following http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/apc/trunk/INSTALL?view=markup) or use PECL do do this for you, if you have it installed.

```
sudo pecl install apc
```

Comment: After installing php-pear and php5-dev, I do pecl install apc, and throws me the next message: http://pastebin.com/A6RnSfCR

Comment: see http://cogo.wordpress.com/2010/07/19/pcre-h-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing-apc-php-extension/ for that issue

Comment: Now throws me the next error after doing apt-get install libpcre3-dev and pecl install apc: http://pastebin.com/rJgCmeJm

Comment: try to `sudo apt-get install build-essential`. if it doesn't work you may have this bug https://github.com/c9s/phpbrew/issues/97 and there is no solution as of yet.

Comment: Do nothing, but I just want to repair my server... What can I do?

Comment: I have changed my sites to .conf extension and it has solved (my VPS is no longer fallen over). Anyway, I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Solved reinstalling the VPS.